# ADC on STM32L100C

Tags: stm32, stm32ldiscovery

I've been reading a lot online to figure what is not working in my code, but it seems like the ADC conversion in my code never starts... Not matter what I do, the EOC Flag always remain to 0 and I am currently out of ideas. Making the ADC work should be simple, but for some reason, I am completly unable to make it work.

I'd be very grateful if someone could show me where my mistakes seems to be. I am using the STM32L100CR-Discovery.

```
/* Standard includes. */
#include "stm32l1xx.h"
#include "stm32l1xx_rcc.h"
#include "stm32l1xx_gpio.h"
#include "stm32l1xx_exti.h"
#include "stm32l1xx_syscfg.h"
#include "stm32l1xx_spi.h"
#include "stm32l1xx_adc.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "misc.h"



void ADC_Initialization (void)
{
    ADC_DeInit( ADC1);
    RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB2PeriphResetCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_ADC1, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM2, ENABLE);

    ADC_InitTypeDef ADC_InitStruct;
    ADC_InitStruct.ADC_ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
    ADC_InitStruct.ADC_DataAlign = ADC_DataAlign_Right;
    ADC_InitStruct.ADC_ExternalTrigConv = ADC_ExternalTrigConv_T2_CC2;
    ADC_InitStruct.ADC_ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_ExternalTrigConvEdge_None;
    ADC_InitStruct.ADC_NbrOfConversion = 1;
    ADC_InitStruct.ADC_Resolution = ADC_Resolution_12b;
    ADC_InitStruct.ADC_ScanConvMode = DISABLE;
    ADC_Init(ADC1, &ADC_InitStruct);


    ADC_CommonInitTypeDef ADC_CommonInitStruct;
    ADC_CommonInitStruct.ADC_Prescaler = ADC_Prescaler_Div1;
    ADC_CommonInit(&ADC_CommonInitStruct);

    ADC_Cmd(ADC1, ENABLE);

    ADC_BankSelection(ADC1, ADC_Bank_A);

    ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1, ADC_Channel_2, 1,         ADC_SampleTime_4Cycles);
    ADC_TempSensorVrefintCmd (ENABLE);

}


int Read_ADC(void)
    {
        ADC_SoftwareStartConv(ADC1);
        int statut = ADC_GetSoftwareStartConvStatus(ADC1);
        printf("%d", statut);

        ADC_EOCOnEachRegularChannelCmd(ADC1, ENABLE);

        while (ADC_GetFlagStatus(ADC1, ADC_FLAG_EOC) == RESET);

        int valeur = ADC_GetConversionValue(ADC1);

        return valeur;

    }

int main(void)
{
    ADC_Initialization();
    int ADC_Valeur = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        ADC_Valeur = Read_ADC();
        printf("%d", ADC_Valeur);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I did manage to find my problem! If anyone ever happens to search for the solution here it is: First, I did mess up this line :

```
RCC_APB2PeriphResetCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_ADC1, ENABLE);
```

It should read :

```
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_ADC1, ENABLE);
```

But it is also necessary on the STM32L100C to activate the HSI oscillator clock, which is not done in the library. Adding this line somewhere in the initialization should work:

```
RCC -> CR |= (0x1U << (0U));
```